# jqgrid - cell data lost when editing before saving

Tags: jqgrid

Whatever the last field edited before saving (if I don't click on any other part of the grid first) the data in that field is replaced by HTML...for instance as the date I enter 07/01/2016 then it saves as 00/00/0000.  When I output the field before I save I see the following html instead of the date: .  The date in the cell is not saved unless I click on another cell before saving.  Please let me know what the solution is for this?

Code:

```js
   jQuery("#billing_schedule").jqGrid({
  datatype: 'clientSide',
        //datatype: 'local',
  //editurl: 'clientArray',
  cellEdit: true,
  cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        colNames:['','Date','Amount'],
        colModel :[ 
          {name:'btn', index:'btn', width:90, sortable:false}, 
    {name:'date', index:'date', sortable:false, width:125, editable:true, editoptions:{size:"20"}},
    {name:'amount', index:'amount', sortable:false, width:120, editable:true, editoptions:{size:"20"}}
    ],
     width: 350,
  height: 175,
  sortname:'date',
  sortorder: 'asc',
  viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: 'css/images',
  caption: '',
  altRows: false,
  beforeEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
   cellIsInEditMode = true;
   editedRow = iRow;
   editedCol = iCol;
  },
  afterSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
   cellIsInEditMode = false;
   if (validateErrorPresent == true){
         jQuery("#billing_schedule").setCell(rowid,"date",validatedVar,{},{});
      validateErrorPresent = false;
   }
  },
  beforeSaveCell : function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) { 
      //validate
   if( iCol==1 ) { //standardize the date
      
      if(d==null){
        alert('Date string doesn\'t match any recognized formats!');
     validateErrorPresent = true;
     validatedVar = "invalid";
     //jQuery("#billing_schedule").setRowData(ids[i],{date:""})
      } else {
        var newval = formatDate(d,'M/d/yyyy');
        //jQuery("#billing_schedule").setRowData(rowid,{date:newval})
     validatedVar = newval;
     validateErrorColName = "date";
     validateErrorPresent = true;
      }
   }
     },
  gridComplete: function() {

  }
   
      }); 
   getExistingSchedule();

<?php 
   $urlToGet = $urlAppPath."php/person_status_includes.php?request=docready&isStudent=1&personID=".$studentID;
   readfile($urlToGet);
?>   
    <?php
 if($scheduleID <> 0){ 
 ?>
          var currentTime = new Date();
         var seconds = currentTime.getTime();
      var s=htmlSendGrid();
         httpObject = getHTTPObject();
            if (httpObject != null) {
               httpObject.open("GET", "php/predefined_schedules.php?action=get&scheduleID="+jQuery("#schedule_combo").val(), true);
               httpObject.send(null); 
               httpObject.onreadystatechange = loadExistingSchedule;
   }
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 
  $("a[rel]").overlay();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added a saveCellBeforeArray();
 function to my save function

before I retrieved my getHTTPObject to save the the database, then it worked.  My save function basically :

```
    function onClickSave(){
      var ids = jQuery("#billing_schedule").getDataIDs();
      if (ids.length>0){        
        saveCellBeforeArray(); // fixed edit load problem
        var ids = jQuery("#billing_schedule").getDataIDs();
        var s;
        //load data from table
        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            s = s+"&paymentDate="+jQuery("#billing_schedule").getCell(ids[i],1)+"&paymentAmount="+jQuery("#billing_schedule").getCell(ids[i],2);
        }
        httpObject = getHTTPObject();
...
```

```js
   jQuery("#billing_schedule").jqGrid({
  datatype: 'clientSide',
        //datatype: 'local',
  //editurl: 'clientArray',
  cellEdit: true,
  cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        colNames:['','Date','Amount'],
        colModel :[ 
          {name:'btn', index:'btn', width:90, sortable:false}, 
    {name:'date', index:'date', sortable:false, width:125, editable:true, editoptions:{size:"20"}},
    {name:'amount', index:'amount', sortable:false, width:120, editable:true, editoptions:{size:"20"}}
    ],
     width: 350,
  height: 175,
  sortname:'date',
  sortorder: 'asc',
  viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: 'css/images',
  caption: '',
  altRows: false,
  beforeEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
   cellIsInEditMode = true;
   editedRow = iRow;
   editedCol = iCol;
  },
  afterSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
   cellIsInEditMode = false;
   if (validateErrorPresent == true){
         jQuery("#billing_schedule").setCell(rowid,"date",validatedVar,{},{});
      validateErrorPresent = false;
   }
  },
  beforeSaveCell : function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) { 
      //validate
   if( iCol==1 ) { //standardize the date
      
      if(d==null){
        alert('Date string doesn\'t match any recognized formats!');
     validateErrorPresent = true;
     validatedVar = "invalid";
     //jQuery("#billing_schedule").setRowData(ids[i],{date:""})
      } else {
        var newval = formatDate(d,'M/d/yyyy');
        //jQuery("#billing_schedule").setRowData(rowid,{date:newval})
     validatedVar = newval;
     validateErrorColName = "date";
     validateErrorPresent = true;
      }
   }
     },
  gridComplete: function() {

  }
   
      }); 
   getExistingSchedule();

<?php 
   $urlToGet = $urlAppPath."php/person_status_includes.php?request=docready&isStudent=1&personID=".$studentID;
   readfile($urlToGet);
?>   
    <?php
 if($scheduleID <> 0){ 
 ?>
          var currentTime = new Date();
         var seconds = currentTime.getTime();
      var s=htmlSendGrid();
         httpObject = getHTTPObject();
            if (httpObject != null) {
               httpObject.open("GET", "php/predefined_schedules.php?action=get&scheduleID="+jQuery("#schedule_combo").val(), true);
               httpObject.send(null); 
               httpObject.onreadystatechange = loadExistingSchedule;
   }
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 
  $("a[rel]").overlay();

    });
```